# simple recursion tracing understanding stacks

Tags: c++, recursion, trace

I'm working on a fairly easy tracing exercise however I'm not completely understanding why the solution is what it is...

```
void f( int n) {
  if (n>0) {
    f(n-1)
     cout << n << " ";
  }
}

int main () {
  f(5);
  return 0;
}
```

the answer is 1 2 3 4 5, however I'm wondering how this is so, since everytime the function f is called it never gets to the cout line...I understand that there is a stacking system where the last function implemented is looked at, however until the factorial example where it returned a value to multiply to the previous n, I'm not understanding how this is similar. Please don't use the factorial example again, I do understand it, but I'm not udnerstanding how the cout is implemented here.. thank you for your help.

Comment: That code doesn't compile.

Comment: The answer is literally a pencil/pen and a piece of paper away. A six-depth call-stack shouldn't be difficult to quill.

Answer (score 0):

It *does* get to the output line, after the recursive call to `f` returns.

The important part here is the *stopping condition*:

```
if (n>0)
```

This makes the recursive call only happen if `n` is larger than zero. And as the recursive call is with the argument `n - 1` it will be lower and lower until it's zero and no more calls will be made.

Lets trace it for you, since you are to **lazy** to do it yourself in a debugger (or on paper):

1. The first call from `main` is made. `n == 5` and clearly larger than zero, so a recursive call is made with `5 - 1`
2. In the second call, `n == 4`, still larger than zero so a call is made again with `4 - 1`
3. In the third call, `n == 3`, still larger than zero so a call is made again with `3 - 1`
4. In the fourth call, `n == 2`, still larger than zero so a call is made again with `2 - 1`
5. In the fifth call, `n == 1`, still larger than zero so a call is made again with `1 - 1`
6. In the sixth call, `n == 0`, which is *not* larger than zero, so no more calls are made and the function returns.
7. Returns to `n == 1`, and so `1` is printed and then the function returns
8. Returns to `n == 2`, and so `2` is printed and then the function returns
9. Returns to `n == 3`, and so `3` is printed and then the function returns
10. Returns to `n == 4`, and so `4` is printed and then the function returns
11. Returns to `n == 5`, and so `5` is printed and then the function returns to the `main` function

That is, this is how it should have worked if it compiled. Now it won't even get this far since you will have compiler errors (with the code as shown in your question).

Comment: In other words, like every other function call, the program will eventually return from f(n-1) and go to the next line. It can't just skip lines.

Comment: @joachim pileborg thank you for dumbing it down for me! I understand it a lot better!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the simple case of calling `f(1)`. We pass the `if` test and make a recursive call to `f(0)`. This call will return doing nothing and continue executing the body of `f(1)`. The next statement is the call to `std::cout << 1 << " ";`:

```
// Substitute the parameter with the passed in argument n = 1
void f(1) {
  if (1 > 0) {
    f(0);
    std::cout << 1 << " ";
  }
}
```

You should now be able to handle the case of `f(2)`, and in general `f(n)`. Whenever you are stuck thinking about recursive programs, consider the base cases and then generalize. Write the code out by substituting the function parameters with actual arguments.